# Syntax error on urllib.httperror in python 3.4.3

Tags: python, syntax-error, urllib, python-3.4

I'm following a book Web Scraping with Python and I'm trying this :

- I'm in a Virtual Environment with python 3.4.3 on OSX
- BeautifulSoup library is installed

When I'm trying this :

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.error import HTTPError

html = urlopen("http://www.pythonscraping.com/exercises/exercise1.html")
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    print(e.code)
    if html is none:
        print("url is not found")

else:
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read());
    print(bsObj
```

When I'm running it, I have the following error :

```
    (scrapingEnv)Macintosh:scrapingenv nicolas$ python3 scrapetest.py
  File "scrapetest.py", line 6
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried with "except urllib.HTTPError" in line 6 without any success.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `except` comes after `try`. you are missing some part of the code. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 2):

You are missing your `try` statement

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.error import HTTPError

try:
     html = urlopen("http://www.pythonscraping.com/exercises/exercise1.html")
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    print(e.code)
    if html is None:
        print("url is not found")
```

Edit: you should also change `none` to `None`